# How to add row at the top with DWR addRows function

Tags: javascript, comet, dwr, reverse-ajax

I am following this example [http://directwebremoting.org-demo/reverseajax/peopleTable.html](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr-demo/reverseajax/peopleTable.html)

Here it is adding the rows to the end of the table.

But my requirements is i have to add at the top. Every new row should be a first row.

please help me, i was struggling since 2days to get it out.But No use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @VikDavid I have updated the link plz look into it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that addRows is only adding at the top.

The quickest solution would be to call [in Java] the Util.setValue [after the Util.AddRow] and pass an id of an hidden HTML element. I suggest to use something like current timestamp so it will change byt itselft. This is the method inside Util.Java [have a look at the DWR sources]:

```
public static void setValue(String elementId, Object value)
```

Then in javascript you can "watch" for changes in the hidden field and in case push the last row in the first position.

Otherwise if you want to have a cleaner solution without the hidden field, you would have to override the addRows in JS but then one day you want also to add the row ad the end...

But I guess that the solution with the hidden field is fairly simpler